# Drawing a picture in android

Tags: android, view, canvas, drawing, image

I want to draw a picture (bmp,jpg,png) into the canvas (using the onDraw() method) of a class that extends the View class. I would like to be able to draw parts of the picture, not the whole at once.

I would really appreciate an example.

Comment: Is the image in your res/drawable folder or elsewhere (sdcard)?

Comment: The image is in res/drawable/demo.bmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first realize where the image is located. It can be bundled in your application in res/ or assets/ directory; or it can be loaded from SD card or internet. That will determine the way you'll obtain a [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) object, representing your image. If you distribute the image along with your application, place it in res/ or assets/ directory of your project. The difference is how you refer to the file - when in res/ you use R.drawable. id-s, when in assets/ you use filename.

To draw a portion of a Bitmap object on a Canvas, call the [drawBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) method.